# Can an istream variable be a class variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream

While developing a program in C++ using VS2010 , can I define

```
std::istream streamRead(ReadBuf&); // struct ReadBuf : public std::streambuf declared before
```

and use this `streamRead` in multiple functions in  my program?

If not, can anyone suggest me how to read a stream using `getline`. I have to read the same stream from   different functions.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

The struct declared in my header file is as below:

```
struct ReadBuf : public std::streambuf
{
    ReadBuf(PBYTE s,size_t n)
    {
        setg((char*)s,(char*) s,( char*)s + n);
    }
};
```

I have a buffer in memory and the input to my program is its pointer and size. Using the above structure, I copy it to a streambuffer. Now I have to read this streambuffer line by line. This is my requirement.

For example some of my functions are:

```
int GetSessionN(int session_id,SessionDetail &N_session);

int GetInstanceId(string header,SessionDetail &N_session);

int GetDriverDetails(string body_data,SessionDetail &N_session);
```

I have to read the first `n` lines from the stream using `GetSessionN` and then the successive `n` lines in the next function and so on.

This is where I initialise the object of `ReadBuf`. I am not able to initialize it globally.

```
int SetupLogReader::ProcessLogFile(PBYTE &mem_ptr, ULONG &size)
{
   string read;

   ReadBuf buf(mem_ptr, size);

   istream streamRead(&buf);// Not able use StreamRead declared in header here.
}
```

Comment: That declares a function named `streamRead` that returns an `istream` (by value, which is probably not what you want seeing as you can't instantiate `istream`s on their own) and takes a `ReadBuf` reference as a parameter, please show what you're actually trying to do with code.

Comment: Have you tried it? Of course you can declare a function and call it from multiple other functions.

Comment: Passing the input stream to each function is not an option? Could you add some function declarations where you want to use it?

Comment: `std::basic_istream` wants a pointer to a `streambuf` for its constructor, so you have to make sure that the value you are passing to `streamRead` will remain valid throughout the use of the returned `istream` (assuming you are using that value to construct it).

Comment: @JosephMansfield : I tried it. but didnt work.

Comment: @Anzz Well then that should be your question. "I tried to do X, but Y is happening instead. I tried Z, but it didn't help. Here is my code." Instead you've asked a very vague question that is difficult to see how it can relate to your problem. It's also not very clear how your question title corresponds to the body.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: I defined my class in the header file. Trying to define an istream object there and using it in the `cpp` file didnt help me.

Comment: @didierc : I didnt get that. Do you mind explaining a bit. Also I thought I was using the constructor of istream and not a function. Am I wrong?

Comment: nevermind, I read it as a function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not copy the stream when returning it in the function but reference it, i.e:

```
std::istream &streamRead(ReadBuf&){
  if (_stream == null){
    // create stream
    _stream = [newly created stream];
  }
  return _stream;
}
```

Edit:

You could also use std::istringstream as it already provides the functionality you are looking for:

from [istringstream manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

```
std::string stringvalues = "line1\nline2";
std::istringstream iss (stringvalues);
for (int n=0; n<2; n++)
{
    char val[256];
    iss.getline(val, 256);
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the constructor of istream?

Comment: What's `null`? Why are you suggesting you create the stream in an accessor rather than a constructor?

Comment: I guess `__stream` is actually a global value (or better yet a `static` one), but instead of using it directly, @Denis suggests to use the `streamRead` function to get a reference to it. Also, it's probably `nullptr` rather than `null`.

Comment: sorry to be unclear, this is supposed to be an accessor function in a class where _stream is a private member variable.

Comment: @Denis:  While declaring `istream streamptr` , it gives me error as istream has only parametrised constructor.

Comment: @Anzz: Different question. Why not use istringstream? this class already has a getLine function implemented and should provide what you need.

Comment: @Denis: Yes. I didnt know there was such an alternative. I am a newbie to cpp.

Comment: @Denis: I could mark it as the answer if u can post it